# Current best output-sensitive algorithm for computing all maximal cliques of a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, clique

I am looking for a reference on the most optimal output-sensitive algorithm currently available for listing all maximal cliques in a graph.

I know the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) is highly utilized, but it is not output sensitive (i.e., the expected running time does not depend on the output).

There is also the [Tsukiyama et al. algorithm](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0206036) that lists all maximal independent sets (i.e., maximal cliques in the complement graph) in time $O(nm \mu)$ where $n,m, \mu$ are the number of vertices, edges, and maximal independent sets of the graph, respectively.

Do algorithms exist for this task with better output-sensitive time complexity bounds, and if so, what is the best one?